# python pandas summarizing nominal variables (counting)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, summarize

I have following data frame:

```
KEY PROD PARAMETER Y/N
1    AAA    PARAM1   Y
1    AAA    PARAM2   N
1    AAA    PARAM3   N
2    AAA    PARAM1   N
2    AAA    PARAM2   Y
2    AAA    PARAM3   Y
3    CCC    PARAM1   Y
3    CCC    PARAM2   Y
3    CCC    PARAM3   Y
```

I am interested in summarizing Y/N column values by PROD and PARAMETER columns and get the following output:

```
PROD  PARAM Y N
 AAA PARAM1 1 1
 AAA PARAM2 1 1
 AAA PARAM3 1 1
 CCC PARAM1 1 0
 CCC PARAM2 1 0
 CCC PARAM3 1 0
```

While Y and N values are counts of Y/N column values from the original data frame.

Comment: Hi Felix, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried pd.melt and pd.pivot_table. No success

Comment: Hey Felix, can you give us a sample of the df in a code line so we can play with it?

Comment: @StevenG, [read_clipboard()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html) is your friend ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) by creating an additional column with the value 1 as it doesn't matter either ways (You are only counting them)

```
df['Y/Ncount'] = 1

df = df.pivot_table(index=['PROD', 'PARAMETER'], columns=['Y/N'], values=['Y/Ncount'], 
                    aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)

df.columns = [col for col in df.columns.get_level_values(1)]
df.reset_index()
```

[image]

---

The simplest operation to use under this scenario would be [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) which would produce the frequency counts of values present inside the Y/N column:

```
pd.crosstab([df['PROD'], df['PARAMETER']], df['Y/N'])
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about `crosstab`! Nice solution!

Comment: Even me. Just remembered about it. Was thinking along the lines of `groupby`/ `pivot` before.

Answer (score 3):

You want to get the counts of the values in the `Y/N` column, grouped by `PROD` and `PARAMETER`.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO('''\
KEY PROD PARAMETER Y/N
1    AAA    PARAM1   Y
1    AAA    PARAM2   N
1    AAA    PARAM3   N
2    AAA    PARAM1   N
2    AAA    PARAM2   Y
2    AAA    PARAM3   Y
3    CCC    PARAM1   Y
3    CCC    PARAM2   Y
3    CCC    PARAM3   Y
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)

res = (df.groupby(['PROD', 'PARAMETER'])['Y/N'] # Group by `PROD` and `PARAMETER`
                                                # and select the `Y/N` column
         .value_counts()                        # Get the count of values
         .unstack('Y/N')                        # Long-to-wide format change
         .fillna(0)                             # Fill `NaN`s with zero
         .astype(int))                          # Cast to integer
print(res)
```

Output:

```
Y/N             N  Y
PROD PARAMETER      
AAA  PARAM1     1  1
     PARAM2     1  1
     PARAM3     1  1
CCC  PARAM1     0  1
     PARAM2     0  1
     PARAM3     0  1
```